# What does CT stand for in the context of a news article?

Tags: acronyms

Does **CT** mean anything in an editorial context? A slashdot article summary is as follows:

> For some time now, rumors have been floating around that Sony was working on a concept for a mobile phone that also serves as a bona fide portable games console... For Sony buffs, you'll be interested to know that there's no Memory Stick slot here, but there is support for microSD cards." **CT**: Which would all be well and good if it was real.

I feel like the last sentence was tacked on after the article was already published. Is it just the initials of an editor or something else?

Comment: Link to the article in question: http://games.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=10/10/27/0656201

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like the initials of the editor.

Comment: You're right - Slashdot's editor's handle is "Commander Taco", or **CT**.